# vulkan gives strange result after switching projection matrix

Tags: 3d, vulkan

[image]

The images to the left are the perspective projection results. The images to the right are the corresponding orthogonal projection results.
These images are screenshots before and after switching projection matrix at runtime. The camera stays the same. Nothing but the projection matrix is changed.

I'm pretty new to this. But I don't think the orthogonal images are correct.

The orthogonal parameters:

```
left: 0
right: 1920
bottom: 0
top: 1080
Near: 0
Far: 1000
```

The orthogonal matrix:

```
0.00104167 0           0       0
0          0.00185185  0       0
0          0           -0.002  0
-1         -1          -1      1
```

Comment: "*The images to the right are the corresponding orthogonal projection results.*" Define "corresponding". A perspective projection has a different shape from an orthographic one.

Comment: @NicolBolas But the orthogonal images above seem like broken.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got one that worked for me: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Library/Source%20Files/10%20Helper%20Recipes/05%20Preparing%20an%20orthographic%20projection%20matrix.cpp

A little different from the glm functions. Don't know why.

Comment: With out massive edits, this answer will be flagged, and held against you in future interactions on stack overflow.  Please edit this answer to stand alone with out needing to follow a link.

Comment: @opa As I said. I have no idea what's going on. And I don't think I have the right to copy the content of the link.